# Paste.httpserver - serve on socket

Tags: python, wsgi, buildout, diazo, paster

I am working with python buildout and want do deploy a diazo wsgi. So far, I managed to do so, but I want to make the app listen on a **socket file**, not an Ip:Port.

Is this possible with paste.httpserver or is there an alternative package to serve that provides just a socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it is possible with `waitress`

First `bin/pip install waitress`, then review your proxy.ini and edit the `server:main` section, to use waitress instead of `paste.httpserver`

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
unix_socket = var/run/diazo.sock
```

Voila. Paster is now serving HTTP on a unix socket.